# How to use in_array function in Blade template in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

How can we use `in_array` function in a Blade template, in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `in_array` function normally as you'd do in a normal php file without the use of blade templating language. In your view `something.blade.php`, you can do something like:

```
<?php
    if (in_array($something, $an_array)) {
        echo "Yes";
    }
?>
```

If you want to `in_array` function inside an if statement, you can use the blade templating syntax for if statement, like following:

```
 @if (in_array($something, $an_array))
      <span>Something</span>
 @endif
```

But I highly recommend you not to call the `in_array` function or any other php functions inside the view file. Instead you can call the `in_array` function in the controller and only pass the variable containing the result to the view to display.

Comment: I satisfied with your comment 
" I highly recommend you not to call the in_array function or any other php functions inside the view file. Instead you can call the in_array function in the controller and only pass the variable containing the result to the view to display. "
But I need solution for blade like twig support {% if $needle in $array %}. So is there any solution for blade template like twig.

Comment: I have updated my answer, if you want to use `in_array` function inside an if statement in the template.